# Codeffects RuleEngine: Method Datasource parameter with type string

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I would like to ask you for your help with the definition of the method parameter.

I have this method definition:

```
[Method("Date from DataField")]
public DateTime DateTimeFromDataField([Parameter(DataSourceName = DataSourceHolders.InputTemplatesDataTreeSource, ValueInputType = ValueInputType.All)] string nodeKey) 
{
         /* some return code */ 
}
```

My problem is that I have the parameter with the datasource type string. This parameter is ignored. I found this part of your documentation:

> • **DataSourceName Type :** 
>   System.String Used only in rule action or
>   in-rule method parameters that represent System.Int parameters of
>   qualified .NET methods, and is ignored for parameters of other types.
>   Gets or sets the unique name of the Dynamic Menu Data Source declared
>   by the SourceAttribute on the source object. If set, the rule author
>   can only select the value from the menu of items supplied by the data
>   source method.

I would like to ask you whether there is other solution how to pass string value as datasource parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Effects rule editor doesn't support string IDs in menu data sources. You can always add auto-incrementing column to your table and use it instead of the string ID. That's the most common way to replace strings with integers.

Comment: I very much appreciate your prompt response.

Not everybody has the data presentend in tables. There are also other data structures. ;-) I have a tree structure that can be dynamically edited. And the string key is unique path to node - and this key is independ of the order which can be changed by user.

Possibility to pass string value would be the esiest way for me. Now I have to manage number indexes and for me it is unnecessary code.

I think that string value limitation is infelicitous. 

I have to implement a workaround.